# scheduler for PCF for .NET console application

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I have created a simple HelloWorld .NET core 2.0 console application. I want to schedule it to run every 5 minutes using scheduler for PCF service.

The steps I followed are:

1. deployed the HelloWorld app to PCF using 'cf push' command
2. Selected "Scheduler for PCF" service in MarketPlace in PCF console.
3. I gave the scheduler a name and bound it to the HelloWorld app in PCF console
4. Then I am struggling to create a job
   $ cf create-job HelloWorld my-job COMMAND

**But I am not sure what i should pass for COMMAND argument of create-job.**

If I succeed in creating the job and then I will cron it using the following command:

5. $ cf schedule-job my-job "5 * * * * "

Please help me in this regard. Please let me know, if you need further details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The app should be in app stage.
2. Please ensure you have installed the   latest plug in from pivotal n/w.
3. `cf Create-job <<AppName>><<job-name>> "dotnet <<AppassemblyName>>.dll "<<Parameters to the console application>>""`
4. `cf schedule-job <<job-name from previous steps>> "*/5 * ? * *"`

This link helped be a lot https://starkandwayne.com/blog/schedule-containers-in-pivotal-cloud-foundry/

Comment: Hello, what do you mean "the app should be in app stage", thanks.

Comment: Start the App and then stop the app. It should not be running like a Long running process

Comment: Thanks a lot Venkatesh...apologies for very late response.